# Null results from readHTMLTable in R

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data off a website in R using the XML package, but I'm not getting any results.  My code is below.  The results are NULL.  The first line turns up a null result (it's not finding any tables).

url = http://www.machinerytrader.com/list/list.aspx?pg=1&ETID=5&catid=1015&SO=26&mdlx=contains&bcatid=4&Pref=0&Thumbs=1&scf=false&units=imperial

Code:

```
tables <- readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data<-do.call("rbind", tables[seq(from=8, to=56, by=2)])
data<-cbind(data, sapply(lapply(tables[seq(from=9, to=57, by=2)],  '[[', i=2), '[', 1))
rownames(data)<-NULL
names(data) <- c("year.man.model", "s.n", "price", "location", "auction")
head(data)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Don

Comment: your first line gives me a list of 0.

Comment: Yeah that's definitely where the issue stems from, but I can't figure out why.  I'll edit original question to make that clear.

Comment: Seems like the table is generated by javascript, that makes it a bit more challenging, but have a search and you might get some useful code

Answer (score 0):

It **looks** like it's a wretchedly built site issue. Doing the following "manually":

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

url <- "http://www.machinerytrader.com/list/list.aspx?pg=1&ETID=5&catid=1015&SO=26&mdlx=contains&bcatid=4&Pref=0&Thumbs=1&scf=false&units=imperial"
pg <- getURL(url)
conn <- textConnection(pg)
pg <- readLines(conn)
close(conn)
```

has at element [33] of `pg` (in this particular call):

```
pg[33]
[1] "<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>"
```

I usually do a quick debug in Google Spreadsheets via the `IMPORTHTML` function (I actually prefer letting Google handle the data import and transformation in general) and *it* couldn't even scrape the page.

I tried it with both command-line `curl` and `wget` and (unsurprisingly) got the same result.

You may need to go this route: [Scraping websites with Javascript enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362859/scraping-websites-with-javascript-enabled) to get what you need. I might be missing something obvious, though.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer on a different thread.  Basically, you need to use the relenium package in R.

Solution:
[Scraping javascript website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22204382/scraping-javascript-website/22205517)